# 2D Dynamic Array, using two data types?

Tags: c++

I've searched around the internet, and I can't seem to find the answer to my solution (or I'm blind/dumb and just can't figure out how to do it). Part of one of my assignments is as follows:

Constructor – creates an empty 2xn dynamic array. Your dynamic array should start as 2x5 in size but can grow to any length. The default value for empty `elements is “empty” and 0. The class should also have a nextElement variable that keeps track of the next empty spot in the array and is increment each time a data element is added.

Is there a way to create a 2*5 array that will accept string in one of the dimensions and integers in the other?

Comment: You are probably looking for an associative array.

Comment: Either an associative array or an array of structs is what you're looking for.  But to really know what you should do, I'd suggest talking to your teacher/professor/TA.  They know how much you've learned in the class so far and should be able to give useful feedback.